# What does "drop and give me zen" mean?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

What does "drop and give me zen" mean?

Maybe it's some kind of idiom. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Probably a play on "drop and give me ten", said by a military officer ordering a soldier to do ten push-ups. The pun sounds like a self-help book title.

Comment: @Silenus Ten push-ups is hardly a punishment. The usual is 50, or 100.

Comment: Can you possible add some sort of context for this statement?

Comment: @Gandalf - Drop and give me zifty doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Gandalf, I know. The set phrase is usually "Drop and give me twenty." But "drop and give me ten" is pretty obviously what the meme is playing on.

Comment: @medica What I meant was that it was more probably a punishment meted out by a high school girl's gym teacher, not military. [Here is the Ad](https://letmereach.com/2013/08/09/drop-and-give-me-zen/)

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I'm not sure what additional research OP could have done for this one.

Answer (score 7):

***Drop and give me zen*** is a currently popular [meme](https://www.google.com/search?q=drop%20and%20give%20me%20zen&biw=1553&bih=863&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU8aut1LfNAhUERSYKHfV6CKEQ_AUICCgD&dpr=1) featured on t-shirts and inspirational posters.

It is likely a play on the expression ***drop and give me ten*** or its more popular variant ***drop and give me twenty***. These are stereotypical orders given by drill sergeants to soldiers, instructing them to *drop* to the ground and do *ten* or *twenty* push-ups. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drop%20and%20give%20me%20twenty%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) is a link to many books which use this expression.

***Drop and give me zen*** means (presumably) "stop what you're doing and find a moment to meditate."

***Zen*** is a "total state of focus that incorporates a total togetherness of body and mind" ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zen)).

***Drop*** could also be an elided imperative to abandon those things in your life that are holding you back from enlightenment, for example doubts, regrets, and so on. See [here](https://endlesslightandlove.com/2015/05/15/drop-and-give-me-zen/).

Comment: Although to be fair to the military, "Drop and give me ten" would never be heard from a commissioned officer. It would only be issued by an NCO, normally some sort of sergeant.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, you're objecting to my use of "military officer"? Does this usually mean "*commissioned* officer" when not qualified? Isn't an NCO [non-commissioned *officer*], by definition, an officer? In any event, I'll change it to "drill sergeant."

Comment: Depends. Clearly you've no military experience. In the US military NCOs are never referred to as "officers", they are not saluted, and are prone to say things like,  "Don't call be sir, I work for a living."

Comment: Interesting and good to know. Non-Commissioned Officers are not officers in much the same way the Holy Roman Empire was neither holy, nor Roman, nor an empire.

Comment: Again, depends. NCOs are indeed officers in the sense that their orders must be obeyed, and their responsibilities vary wildly with country. It has been said that a Sergeant First Class in the US Army has more authority than a colonel in an Arab army. In the British Army it was traditional (ca WWII) that newly-minted junior officers (ensigns) would do what their sergeants told them, while pretending to be in charge. As a Command Sergeant Major instructed an ensign, "I will call you sir, and you will call me sir. The difference is that you will mean it." It's very culture-dependent.

Comment: Reminds me of the sign on my Buddhist friend's desk. It reads "Don't just do something, sit there!"